# Given an SVG path, how can I programmatically determine the width and height of the shape it creates?

Tags: svg

This script runs unattended, not in a user's browser, so there's no JavaScript or DOM available for getting a bounding box or other similar tricks.

**The problem I'm trying to solve:**

- I have a few hundred SVG fonts.
- Each character in each font is defined by a path.
- I need to determine the height and width of each character.
- Given the following path that describes the character "e", what are the dimensions of "e"?

`M590 -21q-239 0 -381.5 150t-142.5 376v38q0 247 129.5 403.5t370.5 155.5q220 0 345 -132t125 -358v-177h-618l-2 -6q11 -83 68 -136.5t152 -53.5q96 0 153.5 15t145.5 52l80 -206q-71 -52 -183.5 -86.5t-241.5 -34.5zM566 842q-73 0 -109.5 -52t-44.5 -139l3 -5h291v26 q0 82 -34 126t-106 44z`

In some fonts, letters like lowercase L and capital I are trivial.  Find the initial "move to" position, and subtract that from horizontal and vertical lines.  But I can't find a way to programmatically parse the path string to find the dimensions of the shape it creates.

Here's the path for the lowercase L in the same font:

`M474 0h-337v1456h337v-1456z`

The shorthand codes used in the path are [defined here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html), but [this page](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html) is easier to read.

---

**Solution**:

Given my time constraints, I was forced to create a small SVG file for each character and convert it to a PNG and trim the PNG to get the dimensions of the character.

**BUT** it turns out my problem was more complicated than just needing the dimensions of the character.  The characters in some fonts have leading white space.  I ultimately needed to precisely position the characters and the leading white space for the characters as defined in the fonts throws off the positioning when using just the character's width.  I needed to determine both the width of the character and the width of the leading white space.  Unable to use a simple `trim` to get the width of the character and the leading white space, I had to preserve this leading white space like this:

`convert $svg_file_name -gravity West -background white -splice 1x0 -background black -splice 1x0 -trim +repage -chop 1x0 $png_file_name`

I then trimmed the image again to find the dimensions of the character and used the size of the leading white space as a negative offset when positioning the SVGs in the final project.

Comment: @RobertLongson There is no browser or JavaScript involved.  This is a python or PHP script that is processing the SVG fonts. What I'd like to do is write my own getBBox() function.

Comment: That's going too broad then as paths can contain lots of different objects and calculating the bounds of each one e.g. bezier curves is not trivial.

Comment: @RobertLongson My initial gut reaction was to create trimmed single character images with ImageMagick, but [inkscape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525325/get-outer-coordinates-of-a-svg-path-getbbox/10078156#10078156) might work too...  Though I'd love to just call a function on a string and get a height and width back....

Comment: Use imagemagick's `convert` with `-trim`, the remaining size is the width and height of the font. See; http://askubuntu.com/questions/351767/how-to-crop-borders-white-spaces-from-image for batch mode.

Comment: @AlvinK. I think you are right.  I need to move on from this small problem and attack the larger project.  Using `convert` is probably the fastest way (least amount of work on my part) to solve this.  For performance reasons, I was really hoping for a function that mathematically processes the path string.  Maybe I'll revisit this when I have time in 20 or 30 years.

Comment: @Vidbot The space between chars is called "kernel", the white space mentioned above might be related to [horiz-adv-x](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#GlyphElementHorizAdvXAttribute). Also look out for ligature (character pair) since it affects the width too.